# How to make gitlab CI use ssh to clone a repository?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The company I work for has a private gitlab server that only supports ssh protocol when cloning a repository.

Inside this server, I have a `gitlab-ci.yml` file that uses [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) to run some scripts.

The script's execution fails because it pulls the repository with https at its early stage. It generates this error message: `fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.mycompany.com/path/to/the/repository/my_repo.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

Where can I configure gitlab runner so that it uses ssh to clone the repository?

Here's the full execution log.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.7.1 (003fe500)
  on my Group Runner Yh_yL3A2
Using Docker executor with image www.mycompany.com/path/to/the/image:1.0 ...
Pulling docker image www.mycompany.com/path/to/the/image:1.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:474e110ba44ddfje8ncoz4c44e91f2442547281192d4a82b88capmi9047cd8cb for www.mycompany.com/path/to/the/image:1.0 ...
Running on runner-Yh_yL3A2-project-343-concurrent-0 via b55d8c5ba21f...
Fetching changes...
Initialized empty Git repository in /path/to/the/repository/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.mycompany.com/path/to/the/repository/my_repo.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: www.mycompany.com/path/to/the/image:1.0

before_script:
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  # Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/
  # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  # We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  # without extra base64 encoding.
  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  #
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
  #
  # Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
  #
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - infra
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  script:
    - /bin/sh run.sh
```

I cannot find an option to specify whether the docker executor should use ssh or https to clone the repository.

Comment: Did you already see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/ ?

Comment: That document is about how to connect to other servers from docker executor using ssh, which is different from what I want to do.
I want my docker executor to clone a repository using ssh. I can't find a place to specify the protocol used by the docker executor.

Comment: Can you add your current `.gitlab-ci.yml`? It'll be easier to help.

Comment: Hi, @AmirMohammadDadkhah, I've pasted my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.